# Path object ends with "/"

Tags: java, path

I want to know how can i directly append `/` at the end of path object.

What i am doing right now is : -

```
Paths.get("/Test/Location/",Group,database+"/");
```

I don't want to do it this way.Is there any other way through which we can directly append `/`.

Comment: which path you are talking about ? File path in a web application?

Comment: You can use `database.concat("/");`

Comment: What difference is there between such paths? Why do you need the `/`?

Comment: java.nio.file.Path;
java.nio.file.Paths

Comment: As per my thing Paths to be used to get rid of the string concatenation but here i am doing that.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is append a `/` character to a `String`. A `Path` object is not a `String`, you cannot append a `/` character to it. And you don't have to. It's not the last character that determines whether the `Path` refers to a folder or a file.

Comment: Just want to know that it is possible or not. I want to avoid concatenation at all.I Know Path is a different object and Paths is a utility class.This is a executable statement "Paths.get("/Test/Location/",Group,database+"/");"

Comment: There is no difference whether you append `/` in your case or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can write

```
Paths.get( "/Test/Location", Group, database );
```

to get a well-formed Path. There's no need for the '/' at the end.